# Variables de entorn EAS Build

Tags: expo, build, variables-de-configuración

Configure mis variables de entorno para expo con .env, pero cuando genero el build con Eas, no me las toma...como se puede hacer para que las lea?? seguí varios pasos desde la doc. de expo pero no doy en la tecla